# Fetch Google Calendar in a custom way

Tags: calendar

I have to integrate the next upcoming events from a Google Calendar. Just a custom list of the events with a few CSS-enhancements to style the date and the title. Is there a way to do so? I checked plugins etc but I don't find solutions to integrate it in my theme. Is there a way to do this with the rss-feed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See amr-iCal-events-list at wordpress.org

Uses ics file as input

Has some default lists or can totally customize own, has widgets or shortcodes.
Can switch off default CSS and/or add own css